# 256-bit unsigned integer datatype

Tags: rust

I was looking for a unsigned 256-bit integer datatype in rust, but the closest I seem to find is the `Struct bigint::M256` which represent an "unsigned *modulo* 256-bit integer". What does modulo mean in this context?

Reference: https://docs.rs/etcommon-bigint/0.2.10/bigint/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic ?

Comment: Ok thanks, so values larger than 2^256 are wrapped around to 0. This seems reasonable (I will likely never go over 2^256 anyways).

Comment: It might be worth looking at some of the (many) Rust crypto projects. Ethereum uses 256 bit integers and there are lots of Rust crates for working with it.

Comment: e.g. https://crates.io/crates/primitive-types

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks, my application is actually for crypto. ```rust-gmp``` and ```ramp``` are some other alternatives. But what is the downside of using rust builtin ```BigInt``` or ```BigUint``` ? Worse performance I suppose? Ideally I would like datatypes that can be used in vectorized operations by using SIMD/AVX2 instructions.

Comment: The history of computing is littered with people regretting having said “I will likely never go over 2^x”.  Make sure you guard against overflow (unless modular arithmetic is actually what you want).

Comment: `primitive-types` is only version 0.11 though and doesn't even have its readme, so it looks far from stable. It looks like it's coming from one of those blockchain-focuses companies which first had those types in the `bigint` crate then marked it as obsolete, but it seems more stable there. They say to use `uint` instead but it doesn't contain those types. A bit confusing all that, and poorly documented, probably shared as an afterthought. For 256-bit ints, I'd use `ethnum` which seems much more stable, advanced and well-documented.

Answer (score 1):

It means that arithmetic on the number is performed modulo 2^256.